# Select from one of two sources based on column from third source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three databases in my app (I know, right?)
It's essential that I keep them as 3 databases, because it's 1 database for my app, 2 for accounting in 2 different companies (but the same software, tables, columns etc.).

For the sake of simplicity, I'll name them as follows:

- app: database for my app
- db_a: database #1 for accounting software
- db_b: database #2 for accounting software

The task I was given is:

1. fetch invoices from db_a
2. fetch invoices from db_b
3. join with orders from app
4. if orders.produces == 'EXTERNAL' then return invoices from db_b else return invoices from db_a

My issue now is - I successfully fetched invoices from db_a and returned the data I needed, but now I don't know where to go from there.

Should I just use a union where I fetch all invoices from db_a, then invoices from db_b but in db_b I would add extra condition 'WHERE order.produces = 'EXTERNAL' or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing there's a join condition from the invoice to the order you could do it like this:

```
with a as (
    select i.*
    from db_a.dbo.invoices i
    join app.dbo.orders o on i.orderId = o.orderId
    where o.produces != 'EXTERNAL' or o.produces is null 
),
b as (
    select i.*
    from db_b.dbo.invoices i
    join app.dbo.orders o on i.orderId = o.orderId
    where o.produces == 'EXTERNAL'
)
select * from a
union all
select * from b
```

I also expect the schema of the tables to be `dbo` which might be different in your case.

Comment: That's what I did actually, I came to a conclusion right after posting this question.